# Why is this returning blank?

Tags: java

This pulls from a word bank our teacher gave us, and I'm supposed to return the longest word that includes only characters from the top row of the keyboard. Currently it returns blank. Please help.

```
//What's the longest word only using the top row of the keyboard?      
   public static void Question6() {  

      String longestWordSoFar = " ";
      System.out.println("Question 6:");
      for(int i = 1; i < WordList.numWords(); i++) // check every word in wordlist
      {
          if(topRow(WordList.word(i))) { // if the length is greater than the previous word, replace it
          {  
              if(WordList.word(i).length() > longestWordSoFar.length())            
                  longestWordSoFar=WordList.word(i);
              }      
          }

      }
      System.out.println("longest word including top row: " + longestWordSoFar);
      System.out.println();
      return;
   }

public static boolean topRow(String word) {

       for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
       //return true if the word has all of the letters in the top row of the keyboard
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'q') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'w') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'e') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'r') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 't') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'y') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'u') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'i') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'o') {
               return false;
               }
               if (word.charAt(i) != 'p') {
               return false;
               }   
        }
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code already? Also your logic seems weird, the word `qwert` as the `topRow` parameter will return `false` in the first iteration because 'w' != 'q'.

Comment: You are better off using the `contains` function, rather than looping through each character. for better performance. `if (!word.contains("q")) return false;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a ***regular expression*** instead. If `s` is a `String` type then use

```
s.matches("[qwertyuiop]+")
```

which matches one or more letters on the top keyboard row. I'll leave case insensitivity to you.

p.s. bet the answer is "typewriter".

Answer (score 5):

You function `topRow` does not do what you want. It will return false if any of the characters in the word is not `q`,`w`,`e`,`r`,`t`,`y`,`u`,`i`,`o` and `p` **at the same time**. This will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this lines

```
if (word.charAt(i) != 'q') {
   return false;
}
if (word.charAt(i) != 'w') {
   return false;
}
```

Now, what happen if the current character ( word.charAt(i) ) is 'q'? what happen if it's 'w'? what happens in any other case?

Answer (score 1):

Your `topRow()` method would always return `false`, because every character of your word must be every character of the top row at the same time (That's not possible) in order to return `true`. Try using regex.

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong or your function always return at first char?